# Can I have multiple copies of a creature with Cipher?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

As far as I understand, Cipher works like so: when a card that contains Cipher is cast, you encode it onto a spell on the battlefield, like a creature for example. Every time that creature attacks and deals damage to a player, a copy of the encoded creature is made.

If the opponent does not have anything to block a flying creature I've encoded, and for 3 turns straight I can deal damage with the creature that was encoded, does it result in 3 copies? Can you only make one copy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cipher copies the encoded *spell*, not the creature - have another look at the reminder text:

> Then you may exile this spell card encoded on a creature you control. Whenever that creature deals combat damage to a player, its controller may cast a copy of **this card** without paying its mana cost.

"This card" is referring to the card it's printed on, the spell with cipher. So if for example you cast [Last Thoughts](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Last%20Thoughts) (allowing you to draw a card) and encode it on a creature, each time that creature deals combat damage to a player, you get to re-cast Last Thoughts for free (and draw another card). This can happen as many times as you can manage to deal combat damage to a player with the creature.

I should also point out: you can *only* encode it onto a creature, not anything else on the battlefield. (And, I know it sounds pedantic, but there's no such thing as a spell on the battlefield - things on the battlefield are called "permanents", a word you'll see on some cards.)

Hopefully this makes more sense to you than copying the creature - you're encoding the spell onto the creature, tying them together, so that the creature can cause the spell to be cast again.

Comment: "This can happen as many times as you can manage to deal **COMBAT** damage to a player with the creature." -- important distinction :)

Comment: @Affe yay for Double Strike!!! :-)